# continuous function bounded from above on closed set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on a closed set $A$. If for each $a\in A$,
$f(a)<0$, then can we say there is $\bar x \in A$ such that
$f(\bar x)=\sup_{a\in A} f(a)<0$?

Answer (score 2):

No. It's wrong for $A = \mathbb R$, $f(x) = -e^x$, for example.

But it would become true, if $A$ would also be bounded in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

We could say that had $A$ been a compact set. Otherwise, $\sup_{a\in A}f(a)$ may not be attained in $A$.